# What is the minimum memory requirement of jpeg2000 decoder?

Tags: jpeg2000

After reading the jpeg2000 spec, i am feeling a bit lost in the terminologies. So could anyone confirm if my understanding is correct?

The tiles are part of jpeg2000 file which are encoded independently. The tiles are divided into tileparts and which further are divided into precincts. The precincts are further divided into code blocks.
The packets are groups of code blocks.

My questions:

```
a) I AM NOT SURE IF PRECINCTS can  be enabled/disabled? Please let me know.
b) If a jpeg2000 file is encoded with a tile size of 2048, then can it be decoded by specifying tile size of less value i.e 128/256/512? 
c) How can we calculate the minimum amount of memory required by decoder for a given jpeg2000 file?
```

Answer (score 0):

To a) You can not *disable* them in the algorithm. They are required to describe the layout of packets. This layout is called *progression order*. Progression order tells you to what code-blocks a packet contributes data. A packet contributes data to a specific *precinct*, *resolution level*, *layer* and *component*. Thus, precincts are the (logical) bounds of code-blocks.

To b) An encoded tile can't be reduced in size. If you stick to a power of 2 you may be able to decode the full image in a lower resolution level to some extent. That depends on the amount of decomposition steps.

To c) That question is fairly hard to answer. It depends on how efficient your implementation is and on the image's dimensions and color model. For example, a 3-component image with a size of 1024x1024 and a bit depth of 8 bits per sample requires at least the following amount of memory just to represent the whole decoded image:
1024 width x 1024 height x 3 components x 8 bits = 25.165.824 bits (3072 kilo bytes)